# How do I create a pool of connection using commons pool?

Tags: java, networking, ssl, httpurlconnection, apache-commons

I have a code like this :

```
URL url = new URL(endPoint);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

in a method. The `endPoint` used to change for each method call ( after all `endPoint` is the method params ). Since all the `endPoint` are ssl enabled I feel doing a `openConnection()` is an expensive one.

I thought of creating a pool of connection. I used the [commons-pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/index.html) jar. And I have coded upto here like this :

```
class AuthenticationFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<HttpURLConnection> {

    public HttpURLConnection makeObject() {
        return (HttpURLConnection) new URL("someting").openConnection();
    }

    public void passiveObject(HttpURLConnection conn)
    {
        conn.close();
    }

}
```

the `makeObject` creates the new connection and `passiveObject` closes existing one. But I'm struck on it. How do I open the connection inside the `makeObject` without knowing my `endPoint`.

Am I missing the concepts here of connection pooling?

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. First of all, the `HttpURLConnection` uses a pool under the hood to reuse existing TCP connection which is what you normally would want.
Additionally for `ssl` connection it doesn't make sense to even reuse a connection as each connection is unique for each client (since it is secure...)